# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL on RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rds

My staging RDS is kicking back the following error when trying to perform various tasks, such as `cap deploy:migrations`:

PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

My Ruby on Rails application has `pool: 5`, which I changed to `pool: 10`, but still getting error...

My RDS database is a `db.t2.micro` which currently has 22 active connections:

[image]

Is there a setting I can change to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your RDS instance?